# No Browser Open while launching Firefox 47.0.1 : Robot Framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework, selenium-firefoxdriver

> WebDriverException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but
>   unable to find binary in default location, no 'firefox_binary'
>   capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line

```
Test Environment
Windows 7
Python 2.7
RobotFramework 3.0
Selenium2Library
```

Comment: share the code you are using and error trace you are getting

Comment: Thanks, Shubam    I found solution as mentioned below

Answer (score 0):

Created FireFox Profile 
   &
   Set marionette=${False}

```
${ff default caps}    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].common.desired_capabilities.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX    sys,selenium.webdriver

Set To Dictionary    ${ff default caps}    marionette=${False}

Set Environment Variable  webdriver.gecko.driver    ${drivers_dir}  

${profile_dir}    Set Path To ff_Profile Directory

Selenium2Library.Open Browser    url=${SERVER}    browser=${BROWSER}      ff_profile_dir=${profile_dir}
```